# Camel FTP2 consumer with quartz2 scheduler - how to get equivalent of stateful jobs?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using Camel for my first time in a production app to retrieve files from a remote SFTP site.  I thought I had everything figured out, but now I'm stuck trying to get the endpoint to activate based on a cron expression *BUT* without running two polls concurrently

Using Quartz2 as the scheduler with the FTP2 component looked like the perfect solution, *except* that this will kick off a poll while another poll is in progress (the "stateful" option isn't available when used this way), generating errors.

Is there an option I'm missing that will give me the equivalent of a stateful Job?  I'm guessing there is because concurrent polling with a file/FTP consumer doesn't seem desirable much of the time!

Here's a stripped down snippet of my route builder:

```
from("sftp://myhost?username=sftptest&password=password&antInclude=*.csv&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0/2+*+*+*+*+?&streamDownload=true")
    .to("file://c:/var");
```

I don't actually intend to poll every 2 seconds, but this demonstrates the issue.  Since I'm dealing with a remote site on a distant network, I don't want an aggressive cron schedule to result in errors.

### Update

If I use the Spring rather than quartz (replacing "quartz2" with "spring" in the URI), then I get the desired behavior - the polls of the SFTP site are serialized.

So I have what I need (I don't think I need any Quartz-specific capabilities), but the fact that the two schedulers have different behavior seems like an issue.  Does anyone know what the default behavior should be?  Is there a bug here?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, it is just how Quartz works. We had the same issue and to work around it we

- limited the quartz thread pool size to 1
- compared the fireTime exchange header with "now" and if the delta is >1s we stop the route execution

The second point is necessary because quartz queues fired triggers for which it does not have a thread available to execute. If you do not need quartz specific functionality you might indeed be better of with other compoments, like [timer](http://camel.apache.org/timer.html).